# Cannot connect PowerBI to Azure Analysis Service

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

Everything worked well till today. Today PowerBI Service (and Desktop) cannot connect to Azure Analysis Service.
Message:
We can't connect to that SQL Server Analysis Services database. Please verify that the database exists, that the user account used to access this data source has access to the database, and that the database is accessible over the network via an on-premises data gateway.

Database and Analysis Service exists and is Active
As I understand, the user has access to the database (user has Analysis Service role Owner)
Last one I am not sure depends on this situation

What could be wrong? Is there any restrictions on the Subscription, which came into effect today, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - increased Replica from 0 to 1 and now it's working correctly.